# Can you pass Sharepoint 2010 credentials to Wordpress?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, wordpress, single-sign-on

**Background**

With an internal Sharepoint 2010 installation and a virtual machine installation of Wordpress (on the same local network), I've been tasked to see if we can have Sharepoint users log in to Wordpress using their Sharepoint credentials.

The method would be to use Sharepoint as a SSO service that could pass the credentials, once logged in, to Wordpress, where the login would be automated and would pass right to the administration panel.

**Sharepoint to Wordpress**

I've found many examples of [communicating with the Wordpress API from Sharepoint](http://netwovenblogs.com/2013/11/21/integrating-wordpress-blog-into-sharepoint-2013/), but I'm looking to go from Sharepoint to Wordpress, not the other way around.

**Zombie Post**

The Wordpress help forums has a zombie post asking the [same question](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-integration-with-sharepoint) from seven years ago.

**Untested Method from Googling**

I found a blog post showing how to [retrieve login information from Sharepoint using PHP](http://davidsit.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/reading-a-sharepoint-list-with-php/) but not being a Sharepoint expert, I wanted to make sure this was the *preferred method*, or if it would even work at all.

Specifically I see he suggests grabbing the Sharepoint user list via,

```
/* Local path to the Lists.asmx WSDL file (localhost). You must first download
 * it manually from your SharePoint site (which should be available at
 * yoursharepointsite.com/subsite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL)
 */
$wsdl = "http://localhost/phpsp/Lists.wsdl";
```

Is it that easy to grab a user list?

**Alternatives**

Could I return a user list via,

- An SQL query?
- A POST request returning XML or JSON?

**Example data required**

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

would return,

```
array(3) {
  ['username']=>
  string(10) "mynamehere"
  ['password']=>
  string(64) "9a027d0d2c054c0cb18ef22d1d8b88c993998c9b4396f0b6b01da777c2f38aaa"
  ['sharepoint_verification']=>
  string(15) "zoR6n]N?~Mg%YEL"
}
```

Thanks for your help experts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about SharePoint 2010 on-premise and wordpress on the web, architecture-wise is not possible.

But there's a possibility to use OAuth if wordpress is hosted on-premise which we can configure with some OAuth plugin and implementing SharePoint 2013.